# Agent A: Lightbulb and a Hammer

Tags: agent-a-a-puzzle-in-disguise

I am stuck in *Agent A: A Puzzle In Disguise*. It must be something obvious because all the puzzles before that were a breeze.

So I have:

- A hammer
- A lightbulb
- One missing yellow triangle (if that's important)

[image]

What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, a bit of googling around and I have found this video detailing the process:

Just had to hammer the lightbulb in front of the house out.